# How to include/exclude files using Giter8

Tags: scala, giter8

According to [docs](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/template.html#Conditionals) conditional `truthy` could also be used include/exclude files or directories . how can I do it in practice ? if I add all the files and directories to the template, how can I exclude them from the project based on the condition ? 
* According to [this issue](https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/issues/345), it is not possible but according to the docs (IIUC) it should work. This is pretty confusing

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to include some files, you should set its name to be something like `$if(some_condition.truthy)$your_file_name.scala$endif$`

When `some_condition` is false, this file won't be created.

There are some examples in [http4s.g8](https://github.com/http4s/http4s.g8). In directory `src/main/g8/`, there is a file called `$if(graal_native_image.truthy)$native-image-readme.md$endif$`. If the variable `graal_native_image` is set to true, a file named `native-image-readme.md` will be created. Otherwise, this file won't be created.

This method is also worked for directories, as long as you use the same pattern for the directory name.